# Организовать данные в виде вектора или списка

Tags: c++

Есть файл, который организован в виде таблицы. 
Надо прочитать этот файл и организовать данные, прочитанные из этого файла в виде какой-то структуры.
Каждая строка - это новая структура.

Как связать эти структуры в виде вектора или списка или еще как ни будь?

Comment: Как Вас удобнее. Можно или вектором, или списком..

Comment: а как правильнее? у нас преподователь очень придирчевый

Comment: Для правильного ответа на вопрос спросите себя (и скажите нам), какие операции нужны вашей структуре. Операции определяют то, какая структура вам нужна.

Comment: ггг, это уже 18 аккаунт?

Comment: В большинстве случаев, если нужен массив, то следует выбрать `std::vector`. Это общее правило. А потом, по факту, когда алгоритмы станут понятными, возможно, придется заменить на `std::list` или другие. Но в большом кол-ве случаев при небольшом кол-ве данных `std::vector` - оптимальный выбор.